# images processing - How to enable avif support to openresty server from lua script

Tags: nginx, image-processing, lua, openresty, avif

I am using openresty Nginx to server images, how can I add avif support for the same.
currently, image resizing is done via a Lua script.
I found a JS solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64293234/how-to-enable-avif-support-for-a-server)

```
import * as sharp from 'sharp';

sharp('input.png')
 .toFormat('heif', { quality: 30, compression: 'av1' })
 .toFile('output.avif')
 .then(info => console.log(info));
```

Can't find any lua script for the same.

Revision:

my current lua script only resize the image to the requested size

```
local magick = require("magick")
magick.thumb(source_fname, size, dest_fname)
```

I want a lua script to convert any requested image to avif.
JS solution works but can't integrate that in the openresty nginx server

Comment: Since you don't show your existing Lua script, we can't tell you what a good solution would be without changing everything. I'm also not quite sure what exactly you want. Your JS solution only seems to convert a PNG image to AVIF, which is not what you seem to be asking about.

Comment: I want to convert any image to avif using lua
the existing lua script only resize the image for the desired size using magick

   local magick = require("magick")
   magick.thumb(source_fname, size, dest_fname)

Comment: I don't know if magick can do this, but libvips seems to be able to save and load avif images.

Comment: I need something that will convert the image like the JS script